# cocos2dx recording sound android/ios

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I am currently working on a game where I need to be able to record and analyze sound. I basically need to analyze the sound from the phones microphone in (close to) real time and visualize this. It is similar to this question, only I want to do it using cocos2dx if possible.

The task I want to perform is similar to what is discussed this post: [Capturing Sound for Analysis and Visualizing Frequencies in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511250/capturing-sound-for-analysis-and-visualizing-frequencies-in-android) , the difference being I want to use cocos2dx for the visualization.

My question is firstly: is there some way in which cocos2dx supports audio recording. I've searched a bit, but haven't managed to find anything useful. Secondly, if not, how can I link the Java/Obj C platform specific sound recording to the drawing/user interaction done in the cocos2dx c++ code.

Any suggestions or examples of similar apps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are aiming for a multi platform solution? Objective C and Java don't mix on iOS. On Android are you using cocos2d-android?

Comment: Yes I aim on making it cross/platform. I meant linking Java/C++ on Android and Objective C/C++ on iOS. I want (mostly) the same cococs2dx code on both but platform specific sound recording. Unless sound recording is doable through cocos2dx, that is.

Comment: I'm no cocos2d expert but I'd guess it has no sound recording ability. So, on iOS you'll be using AudioUnit, AudioQueue, or the AV media framework.

Comment: Max: my problem is I don't know how to connect any of the platform specific sound recording mechanisms to cocos2dx. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Probably cocos2dx uses OpenAL for sound. So you would record the audio to a buffer then play that buffer back using OpenAL

Answer (score 1):

This comes really late but I was looking for same thing through cocos2dx and I found this good helper classes at cocos2dx forum. It mainly shows manager and helper classes for iOS but it is a healthy start for implementation. For someone looking further follow the link.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/microphone-recording-for-ios-and-android-using-cocos2dx/15254/4