# How can I display the frequency of audio in android?

Tags: android

I have tried [Capturing Sound for Analysis and Visualizing Frequencies in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511250/capturing-sound-for-analysis-and-visualizing-frequencies-in-android) link.

But this app shows only the bitmap graph.

Can anyone help me in displaying the accurate frequency value in a text label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the dominant frequency (or key) sound on a recording or the sampling rate of some audio file?

Comment: Yes, I asking about the dominant frequency of some audio(any outside audio) to be displayed as a value.

Comment: You can port this Java desktop implementation of the YIN algorithm [link](https://0110.be/posts/YIN_Pitch_Tracker_in_JAVA)

Comment: The value displayed is not  not accurate.